# How to synchronize shared variable with two Semaphores?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a exercise where I have a Feast where Person from persons N = 10 eat 1 amount of servings from pot at a time. Pot have maximum amount of servings M = 5. There is also a Cook who fill the pot when it is empty servingsAvailable = 0. Person can't eat during filling. I have to synchronize the threads only chaning the methods fill and getServings from Pot class (these methods were empty at the beginning).

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong in this code? Total amount should be 1000 but it is always less. I achieve situation where pot is filling then 5 persons eat, then its filling etc. but the number of servings eaten is inconsistent.

Person class

```
public class Person extends Thread { // Reprezentuje tubylca
    Pot pot;
    int servingsConsumed = 0;
    public Person(String name, Pot pot) {
        super(name);
        this.pot = pot;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
                pot.getServing(this.getName());
                ++servingsConsumed;
                Thread.yield();
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            return ;
        }
    }
}
```

Cook class

```
public class Cook extends Thread { // Reprezentuje kucharza
    Pot pot;
    public Cook(Pot pot) {
        this.pot = pot;
        setDaemon(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(!isInterrupted()) {
                pot.fill();
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            return ;
        }
    }
}
```

Pot.class

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Pot {
    static final int M = 5; // Pojemność kotła
    private Semaphore emptyPot = new Semaphore(1);
    private Semaphore available = new Semaphore(0);
    private int servingsAvailable = 0;
    private int totalServedCount = 0;

    private synchronized void insertServings(int value) {
        servingsAvailable = value;
    }

    private synchronized int removeServing() {
        --servingsAvailable;
        ++totalServedCount;
        return servingsAvailable;
    }

    public int getTotalServedCount() {
        return totalServedCount;
    }

    public void getServing(String nameOfPerson) throws InterruptedException {
        available.acquire();
        if (servingsAvailable != 0) {
            removeServing();
            System.out.println(nameOfPerson + " ate 1 portion from pot");
        }
        available.release();
    }

    public void fill() throws InterruptedException {
        available.acquire();
        if (servingsAvailable == 0) {
            insertServings(M);
            System.out.println("Fill the pot with M = " + M);
        }
        available.release();
    }
}
```

Feast class (main)

```
public class Feast {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Pot pot = new Pot();
        Cook cook = new Cook(pot);
        final int N = 10;
        Person[] people = new Person[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < people.length; ++i) {
            people[i] = new Person("Person " + i, pot);
        }
        cook.start();
        for (Thread t : people) {
            t.start();
        }
        for (Thread t : people) {
            t.join();
        }
        cook.interrupt();
        System.out.printf("Total served: %d.\n", pot.getTotalServedCount());
        for (Person p : people) {
            System.out.printf("[%s] Ate %d servings.\n", p.getName(), p.servingsConsumed);
        }
        System.out.println("Finishing simulation.");
    }
}
```

And the result I achieve so far:[image] I think it should show 1000 instead of 245 here.

Comment: `totalServedCount` is only incremented when `servingsAvailable != 0`.

Comment: Yes and it is logicly correct, person can't eat his serving if threre is nothing in the pot. It should wait unitl cook fills the pot and then eat. If i count prints there is 245 prints "Person X eat 1 portion from pot" but it should be 1000 prints.

Comment: But `servingsConsumed` is incremented regardless.

Comment: I know and I am not supposed to change this, I am only allowed to code within fill() and getServings()

Comment: Then you can't make it conditional. You'll have to wait till it's refilled.

Comment: Yes and thats the point :D I have to do it using 2 semaphores, order of my actions or locks is wrong somewhere.

Comment: In `Pot` some of your methods are `synchronized` and some aren't.  That can't work because now you are using two different locks to protect the same data.

Comment: And in the case of `getTotalServedCount()` you aren't using any locks at all, which is wrong.  Java requires that you protect both reads and writes or the synchronization is invalid.

Comment: @markspace `getTotalServedCount()` is safe to call after `Thread.join()`.

Comment: Probably already stated but there is a logic error: if a `Person` calls `getServing` and there was no serving available (a valid case) `Person` still increments `servingsConsumed` which leads to the inconsistency.  Since it seems valid that a serving not be available then the `Person` needs to be informed that it was not given a serving (e.g. change signature of `getServing` to return a boolean).

Comment: @shmosel after *n - 1* joins. The `Cook` thread has not been joined. Generally, it’s a bad design to spread the responsibility over multiple classes. It leads to the error we have here…well among the tons of other errors.

Comment: @Holger The Cook thread doesn't modify `totalServedCount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using your semaphores like a simple mutex, without any way for callers to know how many servings are available. If you want to signal the state of the pot, you should be updating them as the servings get filled and consumed:

```
public void getServing(String nameOfPerson) throws InterruptedException {
    // take a permit and keep it
    available.acquire();
    System.out.println(nameOfPerson + " ate 1 portion from pot");
    if (removeServing() == 0) {
        // release a refill permit to the Cook
        emptyPot.release();
    }
}

public void fill() throws InterruptedException {
    // wait till pot is empty
    emptyPot.acquire();
    insertServings(M);
    System.out.println("Fill the pot with M = " + M);
    // release a permit for each serving
    available.release(M);
}
```

Comment: `You're using your semaphores like a simple mutex` which might be the point of the exercise, though I agree the instructions seem weird.  What puzzles me is the use of `synchronized` on some methods, but not all.  There's some clear violations of *happens-before* there.

Comment: It's almost perfect but somethimes 3,4,6,7 or more people eat from pot after refilling which is kind of weird because M is equal 5. Do you know what causes this situation?

Comment: @Holger Why not? Whoever takes the last serving does it.

Comment: @MrFisherman There was a race condition where the first message could get printed after the pot is refilled and new servings are consumed. Try it now with the print before the release.

Comment: Ok, that’s what I was missing… Wasn’t obvious as the code of `removeServing()` is several pages to scroll away.